# Can SignalR call single function on any method received?

Tags: javascript, signalr

I want to create testing app for SignalR. I want to show all received data in browser. But in all tutorials I should use something like this:

```
connection.on("<method>", data => receiveMessage(data));
```

But I don't have some specific method. I want to call `receiveMessage` on any message received. Is there something like this?

```
connection.on("*", (data, methodName) => receiveMessage(data));
```

Thanks!

Comment: Do you really need this? Can you just call the method something generic e.g. `myMethodForAnyOtherMessage` for any misc messages? I'm saying this because I think there might not be a way to do this directly

Comment: I need this for testing real server app. I don't want to change method names. I can put there all methods that I call from server, but after some time and some changes it will be hard to maintain. It's not universal.

Comment: Can you have all the methods call the same function at the beginning? Does that help?

Answer (score 0):

There is not enough place to write all this in the comments and I want to make the suggestion to OP, just in case it maybe will help them. Thank you.

---

How about just repeat the method names? something like this:

```
connection.on("method1", data => receiveMessage(data));
connection.on("method2", data => receiveMessage(data));
connection.on("method3", data => receiveMessage(data));
```

If you have many method names, maybe create a loop?

```
for (var i = 0; i<methodNames.length; i++) {
   connection.on(methodNames[i], data => receiveMessage(data));
}
```

I know it's not what you're asking for but I think there isn't a way to do what you ask.

Comment: OP is asking how to get the available method names, in cases where they are not known beforehand.

Comment: I had a feeling I'll get a -1 on this. "I know it's not what you're asking for but I think there isn't a way to do what you ask." Maybe that wasn't good explanation so I added more to why I added this as an answer. Thanks